# p:dialog not showing in tabs on tabview

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, popup

I have a weird problem with JSF2 Primefaces 5.2. This can be easily replicated using the code below.

I am creating a dialog inside a tab (inside tabview) using the onclick of p:command button. The first tab, it works fine. After adding a new tab dynamically (using the value attribute of p:tabView), the dialog is working fine on the second tab as well.

However, if I click on the first tab again and click the command button, the whole page gets dimmed out and I am not able to click anywhere on the screen.

Any ideas? thank you.

```
                <p:panel header="materials Pages" id="materialsPagesPanel">
            <p:commandButton value="+ Add material Page" id="addmaterialPage"
                                action="#{guideBean.addmaterialPage}" ajax="true" process="@this" update="createGuideForm"/>

        <p:tabView value="#{guideBean.materialComboList}" var="materialCombo" orientation="left" id="materialsTabs" activeIndex="#{guideBean.materialActiveTab}">
            <p:tab title="material Page #{materialCombo.pageNumber}">

                <div class="materialPageHeading"><h:outputText value="material Page #{materialCombo.pageNumber}"/></div>   

                <p:commandButton id="pickmaterialsButton" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" value="Pick materials" process="@this"/> 

                <p:dialog header="Search for materials" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" width="900" height="600" resizable="false">

                        Testing
                    <br />
                    <p:commandButton value="Select" process="@this"
                                 action="#{guideBean.savematerialsFromPickList(materialCombo.pageNumber)}"
                                 oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()">
                        </p:commandButton>
                </p:dialog>


            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>


        </p:panel>
```

The code in the backing bean to dynamically add tabs:

```
    public String addmaterialPage() 
{
    MaterialCombo materialCombo = new MaterialCombo();
    //materialComboList is a class variable
    materialComboList.add(materialCombo);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You could try to manually fix the dialog position as solution or at last for testing. Add this style class definition:

`.change-position{ left:10px !important; top:10px !important;}`

And add the corresponding 

`styleClass="change-position"`

 attribute to the dialog.

Comment: I tried but the problem still persists. After adding the CSS, I see the new position of the popup when clicking for the first time. When I go back to the first tab (from the second tab) and click it again, I don't see the popup at all.

Comment: You could then inspect if the dialog is there with your browser Doveloper Tools.

Comment: @lametaweb, I think this problem can be easily replicated. I have modified the code in the original post to have only relevant data, please check, thanks. So, if the dialog is created multiple times inside a tabview (inside each tab), I think it is having a problem, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `widgetVar` attribute creates a global scope javascript variable, so you have to modify your page code in a way like this:

```
           <p:panel header="materials Pages" id="materialsPagesPanel">
        <p:commandButton value="+ Add material Page" id="addmaterialPage"
                            action="#{guideBean.addmaterialPage}" ajax="true" process="@this" update="createGuideForm"/>

    <p:tabView value="#{guideBean.materialComboList}" var="materialCombo" orientation="left" id="materialsTabs" activeIndex="#{guideBean.materialActiveTab}">
        <p:tab title="material Page #{materialCombo.pageNumber}">

            <div class="materialPageHeading"><h:outputText value="material Page #{materialCombo.pageNumber}"/></div>   

            <p:commandButton id="pickmaterialsButton" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg#{materialCombo.pageNumber}').show();" value="Pick materials" process="@this"/> 

            <p:dialog header="Search for materials" widgetVar="dlg#{materialCombo.pageNumber}" modal="true" width="900" height="600" resizable="false">

                    Testing
                <br />
                <p:commandButton value="Select" process="@this"
                             action="#{guideBean.savematerialsFromPickList(materialCombo.pageNumber)}"
                             oncomplete="PF('dlg#{materialCombo.pageNumber}').hide()">
                    </p:commandButton>
            </p:dialog>


        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>


    </p:panel>
```